# No Movement or Color changing when using Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Vista computer and a Millennium Edition. My Vista has Microsoft.NET 4.5 installed and works great, and my ME has 1.1. Well, I've created a PictureBox int a Windows Form. So I can write that the PictureBox's BackColor is Gray or Green or whatever. Ok! But when I try to change it's color after adding to the form's controls, well, it doesn't. It doesn't change color, Size, Location or anything like that. It doesn't interact. I tried to make the same thing with the form but it didn't work. I also tried to write something like : "pb.Update();", but it didn't work. (Changing Form's BackColor, for example). Here is the code:

The code:

**PROGRAM.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MovementTest
{
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Game());
    }
}
}
```

**Game.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MovementTest
{
public class Game : Form
{
    public Game()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        new Ball();
        this.Controls.Add(new Ball());
        Ball b = new Ball();
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(b.CD);
    }

}
}
```

**BALL.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MovementTest
{
public class Ball : PictureBox
{
    public PictureBox pb;
    public Ball()
    {
        pb = new PictureBox();
        this.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    public void CD(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            Game g = new Game();
            g.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Post your code.

Now, Change Game.cs to:

```
    public Game()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        Ball b = new Ball();
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(b.CD);
    }
```

And ball.cs to:

```
    public void CD(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```